# Problem in direction by change language system

Tags: reactjs, react-native

by change the language system in android, my app direction is change and my icon and other text direction all change in app i need the way to disable this option in app to by change the language do not change app elements direction.

thanks for help.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xhgs.gif)

Comment: Any related code or online demo?

Comment: yess i add demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the RTL by using

```
  I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```

reference: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e36247030575e93c1d7087cdb04e1498e9577056/Libraries/ReactNative/NativeI18nManager.js